# PHP generated emails not delivered to Cc

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer

I am using PHP's mail() function to generate mails. Generated mail looks absolutely fine with correct email ids in 'To' and 'Cc' but mail gets delivered to 'To' only and not to 'Cc'.

Here is the code

```
$headers  = "From: xyz@abc.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: xyz@abc.com";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Cc: email1@abc.com ; email2@abc.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". "\r\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Our organsation uses 365 for mails, and this issue has mostly cropped up since we started migration. I went through the php mail log and it seems to be fine to me.

How to fix this issue? Any suggestions?

PS. I feel that this issue has cropped up only since we moved to 365 some time ago. Also, does id 'xyz@abc.com' (sender) need to exist?

Comment: You have no `\r\n` after the `Reply-To` header (or after the `X-Mailer` header). Also, multiple Cc recipients requires one `Cc` header per address.

Comment: I added \r\n after Reply-To/X-Mailer header. Never heard about one Cc header per address, is that so?

Comment: After reading some more, no it isn't. I have always sent my emails with separate Cc headers per recipient, but you can use a single header. However, you must make sure the addresses are separated with commas, not with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: xyz@abc.com";
```

Where is the "\r\n" on this line?

For a proper and standardized PHP mailing library which will help your team to properly build emails, take a look at:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I downloaded and extracted PHPMailer folder in my htdocs. How do I replace instances of sendmail in my code with it? Do I need to modify my php.ini file too?

Comment: I am not a PHPMailer expert, but I think you have your answers here : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `;` to an `,` in your CC line:

```
$headers .= "Cc: email1@abc.com ; email2@abc" . "\r\n";
```

Or send your mails over IMAP with a class like **PHPMailer** https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Replaced ; with an , in the CC line. No change in the situation. 
I am thinking of using PHPMailer.